# How to backup all the emails(content) of Postfix? What folders?

Tags: postfix, backup, email-server

I want to backup all the emails (**their content**) on a server where I run Postfix, so that later on I'll be able to restore the emails, on other server or locally.

Among other folders, I have this:

```
$ ls -al /var/spool/

total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root 4096 May 22  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root    root 4096 Sep  5 18:28 ..
drwxrwxrwt  3 root    root 4096 May 23  2018 mail
drwxr-xr-x 18 postfix root 4096 Sep 11 20:01 postfix
```

What precisely do I have to backup, what folders?

Answer (score 1):

The location where user mailboxes are stored is dependent on your configuration.

From postfix that is governed by the `mail_spool_directory`  parameter  Alternatively you can  choose to store mailbox in a users home directory rather than a system directory with `home_mailbox`.

Alternatively you may have configured a mailbox transport and use something like dovecot to store incoming mail in specific locations, depending on how that’s configured. Check if you do and add those locations to your backups.

In addition to incoming mail , the INBOX, you may be using an IMAP server that allows your users to create additional folders to organize and store their email. You should probably also backup those messages. Again that location depends on how that daemon is configured.