# How do I backup email messages in Dovecot? Where are they located in the file system?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I run Postfix with **Dovecot**. Now I need to begin to backup email messages. What directories should I backup? Such that later, if a server breaks down, I'll be able to restore all the email message on a new server with Postfix and Dovecot.

Comment: please be so kind to inform us what distribution you are using, are you using native administration or some kind of administration panel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to backup all the emails(content) of Postfix? What folders?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033805/how-to-backup-all-the-emailscontent-of-postfix-what-folders)

Comment: Please don’t repeatedly ask the same question, because the answer is the same: it depends on your configuration so start by checking that.

Comment: These questions actually are subtly different (albeit closely related) and I expect them to have different answers, so I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, there is more than one way to skin the cat. But [dovecot-backup](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync) exists, so have a [look](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync), it might be just the ticket for you.

Some commenters advised you to check your configuration and that is good advice. In case you feel overwhelmed by where and what to check, I suggest you start with `doveconf -n|less` and check for the word 'location', in particular the variable mail_location.

You will have a learning curve ahead of you, either way. Good luck!

Comment: Question: How do I backup email messages in dovecot?
Answer: Use dovecot-backup.

Well, at least to me that very much does look like an answer.  Better luck with your questions next time, I guess.

Comment: There're 2 more questions as well in my topic

Comment: @karneliy He also answered how to find out what directory is being used. What other questions did you have?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Maybe his other, implied question was "why do people keep being friendly and helpful even when I am presenting myself as lazy, not following house rules and rude?"  Dunno...